# Show M is the set of natural numbers \0 :2018 in M / M subset of N. m is in M then divisors of m are in M , if m,k are in M and $1<m<k$ mk+1 is in M.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

$M$ is a non-empty set verifying the follow properties :

$ M \subset \mathbb{N}^*$ and $ 2018 \in M .$

1. If $m \in M$ , it follows that every positive divisor of $m$ is in $M$.
2. For all elements $k$ and $m$ of $M$ such that  $1<k<m$ ,  it follows that $mk+1 \in M$

Show $M=\mathbb{N}^*$

***My take :***

I first noticed that , from $(2)$ if $k$ and $k+2$ are elements of M.

$k(k+2)+1=(k+1)^2 \in M$ ,  so from $(1)$:

$k+1 \in M$

If i can prove all odd numbers are elements of $M$ then the problem is solved

My attempt was to try doing this by strong induction as follows :

**Base case :**
It can be shown easily that all of $1,2,3,4,5$ are elements of M

Now suppose all integers  $n\leq 2k+1$ are elements of $M$

Let's try to prove $2k+3 \in M$

We can always write $2(k+1)$ as a prime decomposition  s.t
$$2(k+1)=p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2} \dots p_r^{s_t}$$
and
$p_i^{s_j}<2(k+1)$  for  $ i,j \in \{0,1,2\dots,m\}$

So every prime factor of the decomposition of $2(k+1)$ is an element of $M$

Thus we can always find two numbers $q$ , $p$  elements of $M$ (from induction hypothesis)  s.t $1<q<p$ and $qp=2(k+1)$

We can now use rule $(2)$ to get that $2(k+1)+1=2k+3 \in M$

Thus completing the proof

**S.N**: Sorry for the title , the problem was too long to write down.

Is there any misreasoning in my work ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: $2(2k+2)+1 = 2k+5$, not $2k+3$. Also, if every integer $\le 2k+1$ is in $M$, this includes $2$ and $k+1$, thus $2(k+1)+1 = 2k + 3$ is in $M$. While the prime factorization argument is correct, it appears to be completely unnecessary.

Comment: Well , I completely agree with you  . I have overcomplicated things  , thank you for your comment !